# NetSuite API Error creating order

Tags: .net, web-services, netsuite

I am trying to add an order using NetSuite's .NET example code, however I get the error:

> [Code=USER_ERROR] Please enter value(s) for: Location

I went back to the example and added a location to the sales order...

```
salesOrder.location = new RecordRef
{
    type = RecordType.location,
    typeSpecified = true,
    internalId = "6"
};
```

However when I try to add the order again I get a new error:

> [Code=INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION] You do not have permissions to set a
>   value for element location due to one of the following reasons: 1) The
>   field is read-only; 2) An associated feature is disabled; 3) The field
>   is available either when a record is created or updated, but not in
>   both cases.

Does anyone know what I need to do either in my web service call or in NetSuite to get this working? The documentation on the NetSuite API is atrocious. I am using an Administrator account that was given access to the web service already.

The "Inventory Available" checkboxes for location are checked, which was a possible issue I [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27620064/266804), but checking/unchecking has no affect on getting this error.

Comment: which form are you using? does the web service form has location field enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was able to get past this error. The location was supposed to be set on the Item being sold - not the Sales Order itself! I'm just starting to work with the NetSuite web service and am not digging the poor documentation and error messages.

Comment: Had the same problem just after fixing this error but with the Class/Product Line and Department fields, except instead of setting them on the line item I had to set them on the sales order... Will only get through this with A LOT of trial and error it looks like.

Comment: If you are using inventory it has to put the item in a location (think like a warehouse). This is more under their inventory documentation because if you don't use inventory this isn't a problem.